# Selenium IDE : Select an href in a jquery ui dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, user-interface, drop-down-menu, selenium, ide

I'm using Selenium IDE with firefox to run test on my website, when I'm recording and I click an item in a list, it only gives me one action : 
Click : css=span.ui-selectmenu-status

I would like to pick an item from the list but the class and ID are loaded dynamicly because the site is running with JQUERY UI here.

I'm trying with :

Click : `//div[@id='hlevel-menu']/a[.='CATS']`

But it return an error : not found..

I guess it's wrong or super wrong, if someone knows how to do it, please help :)

Here is the part of code I'm looking for :

```
<div class="dceui ui-selectmenu-menu ui-selectmenu-open" style="z-index: 1; top: 363px; left: 699.5px;">

    <ul id="hlevel-menu" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-selectmenu-menu-dropdown ui-corner-bottom bg_education_icon" aria-hidden="false" role="listbox" aria-labelledby="hlevel-button" style="width: 121px; height: auto;" aria-disabled="false" aria-activedescendant="ui-selectmenu-item-331">

    <li class="" role="presentation">
        <a id="" href="#nogo" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-selected="false">- Please choose -</a>
    </li>

    <li class="" role="presentation">
        <a href="#nogo" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-selected="false">DOGS</a>
    </li>

    <li class="" role="presentation">
        <a id="" href="#nogo" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-selected="false">CATS</a>
    </li>

    <li class="ui-corner-bottom ui-selectmenu-item-selected" role="presentation">
        <a href="#nogo" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-selected="true" id="ui-selectmenu-item-331">PIGS</a>
    </li>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: ah, ok, this is super depressing now that you've finally posted the html. just look at your selector. I'll revise my answer

Answer (score 0):

it's not working because `//div/a` is looking for direct descendants, not all a tags anywhere inside sub children. You need to do `//div/ul/li/a[text()='CATS']`

Then you need to do yourself some learning on [xpath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx)

Comment: Thanks you for your response ! I'm going to try both, I'll let you know

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a jQuery autocomplete? Or a normal  type drop down?

This is how I select an autocomplete list value in selenium: (note this is typed in code, not recorded code). It is a bit tricky, you have to make it trigger the autocomplete, then you have to highlight the value, then you have to select it.

```
string locator = "id=hlevel-menu";
string value = "CATS";
selenium.Focus(locator);
selenium.Type(locator, value);
selenium.KeyDown(locator, "\\40");
Thread.Sleep(50);
selenium.KeyDown(locator, "\\40");
Thread.Sleep(50);
selenium.KeyDown(locator, "\\13");
Thread.Sleep(50);
```

Comment: Thanks you for your response ! I'm going to try both, I'll let you know